# How can I overload operator[] to allow for `object[a] = b`?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

It's possible to overload `operator[]` to take one argument, in the brackets. However how can I overload this operator to allow the user to type `object[a] = b`?

Comment: Of course, you decide whatever is returned, and whatever is returned by the operator can be assigned to

Comment: Technically the way of speaking about it is that your operator needs to return an "[LValue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues)"...which means it can appear on the left-hand side of an assignment.  So basically return a non-const reference that can be a target of the kind of assignment you want to make, and is a meaningful place to be targeting said assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You return a reference to your item, something like:

```
A &operator[](int pos) { return list[pos]; }
```

So when you say `object[a]=b;` it's actually translated to:

```
A &tmp=object[a];
tmp=b;
```

Or in more clear terms:

```
A *tmp=object[a];          // more or less a pointer
*tmp=b;                    // you replace the value inside the pointer
```

Answer (score 1):

The general declaration of the operator (it shall be a class member function) is the following

```
ObjectElementType & operator []( size_t );
```

Answer (score 1):

Subscript operators often comes in pair :-

```
T const& operator[] (size_t ) const;   
T&       operator[] (size_t );  // This enables object[a] = b on non-const object
```